# Nothing happen when I click Role Resources and Role Users

Tags: magento2, user-roles, magento2.4.5, role

When I click Role Resources and Role Users on System - User Roles, nothing happens (no error message. I can edit data on Role Info)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if any browser's extension (not Magento extension) created an `iframe`/ a `div` in your page that overlays these tabs (Role Resources, Role Users). If so, disable that extension (or remove it manually from the Browser developer tool), and you can click these tabs as normal.

You can check it by right-clicking on the **Role Resources** tab or the **Role Users** tab, selecting **inspect**.

In Magento 2.4.5 clean installation, the result for the above behavior is `a` tag for Role Resources or Role Users, see attached screenshot.
[image]

Comment: I solved the issue thanks to your answer. It works after I disable a browser's extension as you said. Thank you so much! 

Comment: Glad to hear that. Cheers!